# Ajax Post Not Completing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am attempting to link together my index page on a website I am creating and my login php code.  However I am running into problems getting my ajax post call to complete.  Let me start off with the index html so you can see the script and the form setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Official Website of Logopedia STS & Carr SLS</title>
<link href="css/landing.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/uikit.gradient.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/uikit.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"> </script>
```

JS:

```
function login()
{
    alert("reached function"); //For debugging

    var datastring = $('#login').serialize();
    alert(datastring);

    var post_data = $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/test.php",
        data: dataString
    });

    post_data.done(function(jsonstr)
    {
        //For Debugging
        alert("works");
        alert(jsonstr);
    });

    post_data.fail(function(jqXHR, text)
    {
        alert("Post failed:" + text); //In case of fail
    });
} 

function replaceAll(find, replace, str)
{
    while( str.indexOf(find) > -1)
    {
        str = str.replace(find, replace);
    }
    return str;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Background Image -->
<div class="bground"></div>

<!-- Banner -->
<div class="banner"></div>

<!-- Logo -->
<div class="tempLogo"></div>

<p class="contxt">This website is currently under construction.<br/><br/>
If you are an administrator of this site, please log in below.</p>

<form class="uk-form" id="login">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <label for='username'>Username</label> 
        <input name="uname" id="uname" type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" /><br /><br/>
        <label for='password'>Password</label> 
        <input name="pword" id="pword" type="password" size="40" maxlength="40" /><br/>
        <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary" name="btnlin" height="15" width="30" onclick="login()">Login</button>
        <button class="uk-button uk-button-danger" name="btnlout" height="15" width="30">Logout</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

So I thought that maybe my php code was the problem and it was not executing properly somewhere (the webhost for this site does not allow php error output) so I decided to make a simple test php file to test with.  Here is that:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['uname'];

$args = array($username => 1);

echo json_encode($args);
?>
```

However then I put something in the uname field and click login, while the test alerts before the ajax call fire, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to do what you want is to use the complete parameter of `$.ajax()`. You can find information about it on [jquery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Bascially you would remove the `post_data.done` call and move the function inside `$.ajax()` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/test.php",
    data: dataString,
    complete: function(jsonstr){
        //For Debugging
        alert("works");
        alert(jsonstr);
    }
});
```

`$.ajax()` also has success and error parameters that accept functions the same way as complete does that you can use to see when the page is working properly.

If that's still not working, try putting the full path in the url field, also try going to the location of the ajax request in a new tab in your browser. this will verify that the php code is working properly and it is a javascript issue.

Comment: Altered the code as you suggested, still not getting through.  I also attempted the other suggestions.  Using the full url to the php file resulted in the same problem.  I then browsed directly to the php file and got this: {"":1} so at least that part is working.  Not sure what could be wrong in the javascript.  Also I had read that success: and the others were now deprecated in favor of the .done, .fail, and other such deferred functions on the JQ documentation page for .ajax.

Comment: I got it working finally but I had to do things a bit differently.  Had to do a submit, but then block the event and run the ajax instead.  See here for an example: http://devzone.co.in/jquery-serialize-function-ajax-post-bigger-html-forms/

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code into a file and removed the alerts and used firebug to step through the code and finally saw it. Your issue is/was a typo. In `login()` you declare `datastring` all lowercase. When you reference it in your ajax request it is `dataString` camel cased. javascript sees that as an unknown variable and crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say you made your code complicated, i tried to make some changes in your code. 
Probably that might work for you.

**jQuery Code:-**

```
function myAjaxCall() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url+'users/validateUsername',
        data: dataString,
        async:false,  // It will not jump to next statement before completing the current one.
        cache: false, // Cache issue
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#availability_loader').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#availability_loader').hide();
        },
        data: 'username='+username+'&usertype='+userType,
        success: function(data){ // Response from php file
         alert("SECCESS-123");

         if(response=="SUCCESS") { //echo a "SUCCESS in you php code
            return true; // It will automatically submit the form after getting the response from PHP
         }
        },
        error: function(data) {
         alert('ERROR OCCURRED');
       }
    });
  return false; // It will not let the form submit
}
```

**HTML form:-**

```
<form class="uk-form" id="login" onsubmit="return myAjaxCall()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for prosperity and if others wonder if I got my original code to work, I did and here is what it looks like now:

```
    function onLogin()
    {
        alert("reached function"); //For debugging

        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "php/login.php",
            type: "post",
            data: $('#login').serialize(),
            success: function(jsonstr)
            {
                onSuccess(jsonstr);
            }
        });
    }

    function onSuccess(jsonObj)
    {
        alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));

        var returnedData = data;
        returnedData = replaceAll('{', '', returnedData);
        returnedData = replaceAll('}','', returnedData);
        returnedData = replaceAll('"','', returnedData);

        alert(returnedMedia);

        var rD;

        rD = returnedData.split(":");

        if (rD[1] === "Username field empty")
        {

        }
    }
```

My problem was a few.  First I was not properly returning the data from my PHP file.  Second I was not handling the returned json object correctly.  And lastly my original code had a case issue in it with my datastring variable (declared as datastring but tried to pass through the post as dataString).

Fixed all of these up and now it works like it should with both the test.php file and the changed areas for testing in my login.php file.